# Reading Two Int4 from a Byte into two Seperate Bytes and Vice Versa

Tags: c#, byte, bitwise-operators

Okay so this may sound ridiculous, but as a personal project, I am trying to re-create a TCP networking protocol in C#.

Every TCP packet received has a header that must start with with two Int4 (0 - 15) forming a single Byte. I think using bitwise operators I have extracted the two Int4 from the byte:

```
Byte firstInt4 = headerByte << 4;
Byte secondInt4 = headerByte >> 4;
```

The issue is that I now need to be able to write two Int4 to a single Byte, but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *bitwise* operations will do:

**Split:**

```
byte header = ...

byte firstInt4 = (byte) (header & 0xF);     // 4 low  bits
byte secondInt4 = (byte) (headerByte >> 4); // 4 high bits
```

**Combine:**

```
byte header = (byte) ((secondInt4 << 4) | firstInt4);
```

Answer (score 0):

An int4 is called a "nibble": half a byte is a nibble.  :)

Something like:

```
combinedByte = hiNibble;
combinedByte << 4;  // Make space for second nibble.
combinedByte += loNibble;
```

should do what you want.

Comment: `|` is the canonical method to do this, not `+=`